# Is there any Flutter/Dart Package that can segment video and add comments on them?

Tags: reactjs, flutter, dart, video-editing, flutter-video-player

I am quite new to Flutter and I am hesitating to use it for my next project.

What I want :

-The possibility to segment video (like in Youtube bar, to show differents parts of the video)[image]

-The possibility to add text comments inside the video for a certain timeframe to another

Do you guys know any package that can do that for me ?
Or maybe another language where a package like this is existing ?
Since it is the biggest feature, my choice of dev language will probably revolve around this possibility.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I don't think that there is an especial package for this. you have to get connected to video and render the widget based on the video time. maybe using a Stack widget to achieve this.

Comment: Can a stack widget overlap a video ? Doesn't it come with some issues like sizing ?

Comment: I don't think so. You can almost use any widget as Stack children.

Comment: Okay, I think I'll give it a try !
Thanks a lot for your help, kind sir !